# Capacitor Discharge Pin 7 555 Timer

Tags: 555

I am very new to electric engineering, so bear with me ;) Before building the circuit IRL, I wanted to try to build a simple `555 timer` with a simulator following [Ben eater's tutorial on it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kRlSFm519Bo). Here are the [schematics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjyYO.jpg) of the circuit...

[image: Schematic]

If you want to see the [tinkercad project](https://www.tinkercad.com/things/ev4rIVvzin1-sizzling-bigery-snaget/editel?tenant=circuits?sharecode=o1bEIJYku-uPTECMmP_W5YaizCPPIsObtVYOvBrodHU=)... Now, even though I seem to have copied the exact same circuit as shown in the video (or at last so I think) - the first seconds of YT video - the `2uf capacitor` doesn't seem to discharge trough `Pin 7` when I simulate the circuit. What could be the problem here? I am 100% sure I am missing something very obvious but I have tried, and tried and tried to no avail. So I hope you guys could explain this to me :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you have a wire joining pin-8 to pin-7?

Comment: How do you know the capacitor doesnt discharge? If the LED is not blinking, the cause may be the LED is connected incorrectly (swap its pins)

Comment: What you've posted is a wiring diagram for a breadboard whereas we like to work with a **schematic** which is a diagram showing device symbols and, for integrated circuits such as your 555, the pin numbers and functions. That way we can see the *scheme* of the circuit. With such a simple circuit someone will be able to help you out.

Comment: Sorry, without a schematic this wiring diagram is unreadable. Here is an example of a question with a good schematic: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/413326/astable-555-timer-circuit-that-resets-on-a-heartbeat?rq=1

Comment: Like @brhans suggests, it looks like pin 7 & 8 are connected together, but zooming in, the resistor is not stuck into the breadboard. Please improve the image so it becomes clear whether those pins are connected or not.

Comment: Ok! Edited the question and added schematics (the best I could do) @MarkU :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you have your LED pins shorted together. The way a breadboard works is every pin in that line is connected. You need to put the long LED leg in the line with the wire to pin 3 and the short leg on a new line with the resistor to ground

Comment: I am sooo dumb! Thank you sooo much! You're a life saver